# how to pass field value on ng-click in template- kendo UI grid

Tags: kendo-grid

I could not pass the field value to ng-click function,I tried following snippet,

```
ng-click=\"sampleClick({field:#= Type#});\">#= Type#
```

Can any one suggest , we are using kendo Ui grid.